# automatic graph generation in xlsx

Tags: r, excel, plot, xlsx

I wrote a script in R to do some analysis and make the result as a set of table in xlsx format.

However, I would like to have some automatically generated default graphics from these tables in another sheet.

one way is using

```
addPicture(file, sheet, scale=1, startRow=1, startColumn=1)
```

from the xlsx package. meaning generating this plots using R and saving them separating and inserting them in to the excel file.

I wonder, if there is any easier way, using excel functionality. For example if there is any formula for generating these plots to do so ?

Basically, I wonder, if there is any automatic scripting way to generate these graphs ? is there any way, like a formula to do such a thing ?

Comment: To quote the Apache POI project (used by `xlsx`): > Charts: This is a hard problem, with very little documentation.

Comment: One way would be to write a VBA script to generate the graphs, then possibly triggering the VBA from R (but I haven't tried this...)

Comment: The best approach in my mind, is to use an Excel template: create a workbook where the graphs are created from fake data. Then using R, read in the template and paste your real data in place of the fake data. As you open the final spreadhseet, the graphs should recalc themselves automatically.

Comment: @flodel the xlsx file gets cruppted as soon as I try to edit the loaded xlsx. I load the workbook in R, and I can see the rows, but changing the workbook and saving changes, doesnt work ...

Comment: I know you can make it work because I have implemented it myself at work, using xlsx. For your usage, maybe it will be easier if you delete the fake data before saving the template, so you won't have to write over existing rows/cols.

Comment: It works now ! but by using XLConnect packages. It has a very nice documentation as well. http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/XLConnect/vignettes/XLConnect.pdf